# imagecopyresampled (jpg) give me black background

Tags: php, gd

I have a problem with `imagecopyresampled`. So, I crop a picture (jpg), want to add white background, for the output picture ... and it doesn't work ...

Here is my code:

```
$this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($sizes['width'], $sizes['height']);
$white = imagecolorallocate($this->imageResized, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($this->imageResized, 0, 0, $white);
imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, (($selected_x * $ratio) - ($blanc_x * $ratio)), (($selected_y * $ratio) - ($blanc_y * $ratio)), $sizes['width'], $sizes['height'], ($selected_width * $ratio), ($selected_height * $ratio));
imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
```

So, it work, but, the background is black, and not white ...
Here is the output picture ...
[image]
EDIT:
Passed values are (0, 0, 31, -50, 110, 110, 110, 110);
And, if I fill after the imagecopyresampled, it works just sometimes, cause, it adds me domes black borders ...

Any ideas? ...

Comment: What's the size of the statue of liberty image?

Comment: 110x110px. Actually, I add white around the original picture (and resize 500x500px), then, on this new picture, the user can crop (with jscrop). So, i get the user crop from the 500x500px picture, and crop on the originale picture ...

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your colour fill after the imagecopyresampled. It's unintuitive, I know, but that's GD for you...

```
$this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($sizes['width'], $sizes['height']);

imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, (($selected_x * $ratio) - ($blanc_x * $ratio)), (($selected_y * $ratio) - ($blanc_y * $ratio)), $sizes['width'], $sizes['height'], ($selected_width * $ratio), ($selected_height * $ratio));

$white = imagecolorallocate($this->imageResized, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($this->imageResized, 0, 0, $white);

imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
```

If that doesn't (appear) to work, check the values you're passing into imagecopyresampled as the co-ords and dimensions - it's possible to make the copied image bigger than the canvas (or itself) which will bring a default black background with it.

Comment: This just fills the black to white...
(for me)